# Sitecore Analytics: where can I configure reports and see results?

Tags: analytics, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-dms

I've installed new Sitecore 6.5.0 with update 5, and DMS, as it was written [in this blog](http://geshbach.blogspot.com/2011/12/sitecore-dms-installation.html). But I still can't see Sitecore Analytics. I have only Engagement Analytics, and when I open it, it shows the same tree view as in Content manager.

So question actualy is: where can I configure reports and see results? Haven't I installed analytics correctly?

Update: Looked in database - there is data, so I guess it's configured ok. Where can I see results of analysing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to deploy the engagement plan first.

Go to system/Marketing Center/Engagement plans.

Find the correct template, go to Review Tab -> Workflow section -> Edit -> Deploy

Now, the engagement will be available with yoru data.

Kind regards,